# Using Prototype- how do I watch input field for carriage return?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I'm using the JS library Prototype-- how can I watch a text input field and when return is pressed, alert the contents of the field to the user? **(There is no < form > on the page, just the input field.)**

Here's roughly what I want to do:

```
Enter something: <input type='text' id='myfield'>

<script>
  if([keydown event in #myfield]) {
     alert("You typed: "+[contents of #myfield]);
  }
</script>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Is the user using a typewriter? I assume you mean you want to check when the user has pressed an enter key, although I suppose you could check to see if the text contains `\r` characters after any change.

Comment: LOL, someone tell Apple that the Mac is not a typewriter, since my standard Mac keyboard says "return" (and not "enter") on the enter key. ;-) Anyhow, yes, the idea is to monitor the keypresses and act when the user types enter... (or pulls the carriage return bar! ;-) I updated my question with a little meta-code sample to clarify.

Comment: What's the desired behavior when a user hits `Ctrl+V` (or `⌘+V` for the mac users out there) and a carriage return exists in the pasted content? - in hindsight after realizing that you're using an `input:text` element, this wont be an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('myfield').observe('keypress', function(event){
    if(event.keyCode == Event.KEY_RETURN)
        alert($('myfield').value);
});​
```

You can find a simple demo in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UycpM/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://prototypejs.org/api/event

You might get a better answer if you give an example.

Answer (score 0):

Why not monitor for `submit`?

For element `<input id="signinForm"/>`:

```
Event.observe('signinForm', 'submit', checkForm);
function checkForm() { //do something }`
```

More information is found at the docs here:

http://prototypejs.org/api/event/observe

Comment: There's no < form > on the page, so there's no < form > submit event.